# Como usar los parametros de conexion dinamicos

Tags: asp.net, .net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Actualmente este codigo me da un error cuando la session expira, pues pierde el dato, lo que me haria falta poder almacenar los datos de conexion, el alguna variable que nunca se pierda el dato y que sea accesible para todos los controladores.

En las sessiones tengo como me conecto a la BD, no puedo ponerlo en el web.config porque los parametros son distintos, y lo obtengo de una tabla dependiendo de la url de la web

Este es mi codigo.

```
 public ActionResult DashboardV1()
    {              
        UpcomingAppointment UA = new UpcomingAppointment();
        MedicationViewModel MVM = new MedicationViewModel();           
        List<UpcomingAppointment> list = UA.ReturnDataApppointment(Session["PatientCode"].ToString(), Session["server"].ToString(), Session["provider_database"].ToString(),
        Session["user_sql"].ToString(), Session["password_sql"].ToString());
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Date = list[0].TransDate;
            ViewBag.Time = list[0].TimeIn;
        }
        ViewData["CurrentMedications"] = MVM.GetCurrentMedications(Session["PatientCode"].ToString(), Session["server"].ToString(), Session["provider_database"].ToString(),
        Session["user_sql"].ToString(), Session["password_sql"].ToString());                
        return View(list);
    }
```

Comment: No crees que es inseguro que siempre se guarde la session. Yo te recomendaría ampliar  el rango de  días u horas de expiracion de la session.

Comment: si creo que si es inseguro, por eso escribo aqui para si alguien tiene alguna otra via, que pueda usar, cuando la session expira, me da el error, pero la idea seria usarlo de otra forma, si existe

Comment: ¿Como cargas esos datos? No seria lógico que si expira la sesión volverías a cargar los datos de nuevo.

Comment: exacto entonces lo que me haria falta es que cuando expire la session lo redireccione para la pagina de login ??

Comment: Tu mismo lo has dicho. La cuestión seria cuanto tiempo le darías al usuario para que su sesión expire, esto dependerá de que tipo de proyecto realices , considerar tiempo de uso promedio, promedio de tiempo en la cual se puede dejar como en espera, etc.

Comment: no existe otra via que pueda guardar los parametros de conexion que no sea en el web.config, pues los parametros los obtengo de una unica conexion que tengo en el web.config que me dice los parametros para las demas base de datos, que estan en distintos servidores??

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76513/discussion-between-raidel-fonseca-and-bercklyn-carlosviza).